# How can you mock a DOM window event?

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

In my ng4 app, I have a service that exposes an Observable over the window focus event. How would you go about testing this (I am using Jasmine, but that's not very important)?

```js
constructor(@Inject('Window') private window: Window) {

    this.window.onfocus = () => {
        this.onFocusSubject.next();
    };
}

// how can I test that the onFocus Observable is triggered 
// when window.onfocus is fired?
public onFocus(): Observable<any> {
    return this.onFocusSubject.asObservable();
}
```

My approach is to mock the window object and to trigger fire the onfocus event, but am unsure of how to trigger the event...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just mock the service using a `BehaviorSubject` and trigger a `next` call to ensure your listeners are invoked.

Like this:

```js
const serviceStub = {
  windowEvent: new BehaviorSubject(null);
}

// in your test:

it('should trigger an event listener: ', () => {
  const service = componentInstance.injector.get(Service);
  service.windowEvent.next(new FocusEvent('focus'));
  // write your test logic here
})
```